# underlined active page on navbar and scroll to footer on contacts react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react-bootstrap navbar that has links to other pages. I want the nav-link of the page the user is in (active) to be underlined.
I add some css that works for nav items with the "href='#home'" (ashtag) but not with the real links.

```
      <Nav defaultActiveKey={"/"} >
            <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link
              href="/beafounder"
            >
              Be a founder
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/portfolio"  >Portfolio</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">
            <Logo />
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </div>
      <div className="navDx">
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home" >Team</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link" >About Us</Nav.Link>
            
  <Nav.Link href="#contacts">Contacts</Nav.Link>
     
            
          </Nav>
```

I tried to add event keys to the nav link and change the defaultActiveKey but nothing, the nav item is underlined when i click it but the the active item remains the home.

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
```

border-bottom: 8px solid #D6FF0A !important;
}

Comment: also I would like to scroll to the footer when the contacts nav item is clicked, i tried with the ScrollLink and Element of react-scroll but did't work

Comment: Your code snippet is not working. Why do you have two Navs and two Navbar.Collapse elements?

Comment: I was trying something else, but I left them to show that the second navbar does what I want but the first one (with actual links) doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The active link get a class "active" so you can target it with following selector:

```
.nav-link.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Add event keys to all your links. Create a state to hold the active link. onSelect of Nav set the state:

```
const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = React.useState("home");
  return (
    <Navbar>
      <Nav
        defaultActiveKey={activeLink}
        onSelect={(selectedKey, event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("selected key is: ", selectedKey);
          setActiveLink(selectedKey);
        }}
      >
        <Nav.Link href="/" eventKey="home">
          Home
        </Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="/beafounder" eventKey="beafounder">
          Be a founder
        </Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="/portfolio" eventKey="portfolio">
          Portfolio
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
```

I haven't integrated any router solution, that's why I'm canceling the event on select.

Please look into following sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-morning-mfcm5w